# How to configure ajax + jQuery Validation Engine + php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validation-engine

Please help me configure form. It is necessary that the message is not sent if the inputs are not full. And if everything correctly popped up the message of successful sending.

mail.php

```
<?php
$recepient = "admin@*******.com";
$sitename = "********";    
$name = trim($_POST["form-name"]);
$mail = trim($_POST["email"]);
$text = trim($_POST["form-text"]);
$message = "Name: $name \nEmail: $mail \nMessage: $text";
```

script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("#form").validationEngine({
    promptPosition: "centerRight",
    scroll: false,
    ajaxFormValidation: true,
    ajaxFormValidationURL: "mail.php",
    data: $(this).serialize()
}).done(function() {
    $(this).find("input").val("");
    alert("Your letter has been sent.");
    $("#form").trigger("reset");
});
});
```

index.html

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="form-name" class="validate[required]" placeholder="Name" id="id-form-name" /><br />
    <input type="email" name="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" placeholder="Email" id="email" /><br />
    <textarea name="form-text" class="validate[required]" cols="60" rows="5" placeholder="Message" id="id-form-text"></textarea><br />
    <button id="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```